# Merging a lot of containers with STL Algorithms

Tags: c++, oop, stl

I have a lot of lists, vectors, sets ... (what ever you prefer) of pointers called `RealAlgebraicNumberPtr` to certain class. They are sorted.

I want to merge them and of course I want to do it fast and efficient.

What is the best choice? `std::merge` ? Or maybe `std::set`? I can provide both an < and == ordering.

Any ideas?

Comment: `std::merge` is for merging containers. How would you use `std::set`?

Comment: I don't. Its meant as a xor ;)

Comment: @VJo: you *could* insert the contents of all your containers into a `set`, ending up with an ordered, merged collection of all of them without duplicates (or with duplicates if you use `multiset` instead). However, since the containers are sorted to begin with, `std::merge` will be more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, `std::merge` is ok.

Only for std::list, you can profit from the optimization that `std::list::merge` *member function* implements: it splices the list nodes from the source into the target. That way, the source list will become empty, but it will avoid resource (re)allocation

#### Re: `std::set`

you could in fact std::merge into a std::set to get unique values in one go. With generic merge, duplicate values are not filtered, but the result *is* sorted, so you could apply `std::unique` to the result. If you expect a lot of duplicates, you might be quicker using a `std::set`

Answer (score 0):

`std::merge` is as efficient as it gets. Which underlying container you use depends on your requirements. `std::vector` has the smallest memory-overhead of all standard containers, so if your data are large, you should stick with that.

If you use `std::vector`, you should `resize` the target-vector before merging to avoid reallocations (you should be able to calculate the required size up-front), instead of using an `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: "std::vector has the smallest memory-overhead of all standard containers" - although because of the contiguity requirement, and the fact that vector copies as it reallocates, it does not follow from this that `std::vector` is the container that can hold the most elements when you're using a large proportion of available memory. That depends whether (virtual) address space is fragmented and how the vector's capacity grows, `deque` could win.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Instead of recommending `resize`, I'd suggest `reserve` in combination with `std::back_inserter`: best of both worlds: less error-prone (off-by-n reserved size, e.g.) and negligable performance difference